# how to save a file generated in server machine in clients machine(mydocument)

Tags: asp.net, download

i'm developing a system with asp.net, there i generate a powerpoint presentaion in the server machine, i need to generate it there and save it in the clients machine, how can i achieve this? how to access the clients machine and save the generated file there?

ragards,
Rangana

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nope**. That is not possible. You cannot access client system from server-side. The best you can do is **let the user download the powerpoint file on a button click**. You can **prompt the user to save it into My Documents** preferably but you can never force him to do so, it is entirely his preference as to where to store the file.

The web applications work much differently then the desktop clients. Should such a thing ever be possible, **Imagine what if the user is accessing your website from a linux or Mac** machine where there's nothing like `My Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save files to the client machine from ASP.NET. You could generate a link that the client clicks on to download the file and decide where he wants to save it on his machine because you might want to save a Powerpoint presentation but there are sites that might want to save some other things.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, that's not possible.

The best option you have is for instance to have a JavaScript running on your site which queries your server for the creation of the presentation file. Once it is finished you show a modal popup window informing the user the file has been generated and offering him a download link/button.