# How save file from server folder to local drive/client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a formed file in some folder on server. I need to create some solution to allow user save this file local on drive on computer.

Can anyone advice me how it can be done, what control I should use.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491174/how-to-save-a-file-generated-in-server-machine-in-clients-machinemydocument**

Comment: It's not programmatic file save on client, user will initiate the process as mentioned in the post, If i understand that correctly.

Comment: Is this file hosted on IIS server inside some virtual directory? I hope this file doesn't contain important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will open the Browser SaveAs dialog:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/imgName.jpg"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    fs.Close();
    SetResponse("imgName");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
}

private static void SetResponse(string fileName)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".jpg";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
}
```

try opening the FileStream with this permissions:

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/imgName.jpg"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. But now on FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/imgName.jpg")); it returns exception: the file already used! Can I to go round that?

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem, post the previous segment of code, where you use the file.

Comment: the file NameDB.mdf file, the data base. It used all over the project. I try to allow some users to copy data base file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321077/cant-access-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to put a link of your file in aspx page.

```
<a href="path to your file on server">some text here</a>
```

When user click on this link they will got the download dialog box using which they can save the file to there local system.